# if params[:attribute] == true then do "X" in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

How to trigger `#x` condition if `:someday` is equal to `true`?

**db**

```
t.boolean  "someday"
```

**controller**

```
# In new.html.erb user inputs challenge.name and can checkmark challenge.someday
def new
  @challenge = Challenge.new
end

# If user checkmarks someday than do x otherwise do y (keep in mind conditional is triggered before challenge is created)
def create
  if params[:someday] == true
    #x
  else
    #y
  end
end
```

**console**

```
Started POST "/challenges" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-03 14:04:01 -0400
Processing by ChallengesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ii3RdJYAnOpT/OOkqVA74b8YD5suUA3Rf4Wegih65xSSU0r1c5DB0UCJVWcGcid3JtSt6fjzmfYpbWZtf2Dm/A==", "challenge"=>{"someday"=>"1", "name"=>"test"}, "button"=>""}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 15]]
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered challenges/create.html.erb within layouts/application (48.5ms)
```

Right now no matter how I've tweaked `params[:someday] == true` the `#y` condition keeps getting triggered. I've tried, `params[:someday] == "true"`, `params[:someday] == 1`, `params[:someday] == "1"`, `params[:someday] == "t"`

Comment: Put a debugger like pry, or a logging statement, just above your `if` statement. When you think you've set the value of `:someday` to be true, what is its actual value at that line of code?

Comment: Do I just put `pry` above the line?

Comment: Looking at your parameters, I see `:someday` set inside a `:challenge` param. What happens if you check for `params[:challenge][:someday] == 1`?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com how looks yr `form` ? can u share it only that part related to `:someday`

Comment: Updated question @7urkm3n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You should do `params[:challenge][:someday]` as the `someday` is inside the `challenge` hash. The below code should work

```
def create
  if params[:challenge][:someday] == "1"
    #x
  else
    #y
  end
end
```

Comment: No that didn't do it. Still went to #y

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Try `params[:challenge][:someday].to_i == 1` or  `params[:challenge][:someday] == "1"`

Comment: The latter is what did :) Probably the only thing under the sun I didn't try

Answer (score 0):

the `params[:someday]` should be `params[:challenge][:someday]` since the value you are submitting is from a form

```
def create
  if params[:challenge][:someday]
    #x
  else
    #y
  end
end
```

will do the trick

Comment: No that didn't do it. Now it always go to #x

Comment: change your form checkbox to `f.check_box :someday, {}, "true", "false"` then try it out

Answer (score 0):

Your `check_box` in html returns `1`, if you want it return boolean then do like below. Also, in controller params should like this: `params[: challenge][:someday]`

**form**

```
<%= f.check_box :someday, {}, true , false %>
```

**controller**

```
def create
  if params[: challenge][:someday]
    #x
  else
    #y
  end
end
```

Comment: Still went to #y even with `true` or `1`  as condition